# How to find using jQuery to find text that contain a specific text

Tags: jquery

I want to get the value of steve only in alert like this.

```
<div class="value">333</div>
```

---

Below is my code

```js
var a = $("p:contains('Steve')").text();
alert('<div class="value">' + a + '</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  John: 111
  <br>Sam: 222
  <br>Steve: 333
</p>
```

Comment: Please paste HTML code inside a code block, not just into the page. When you do that, it appears as plain text with no HTML showing and we cannot see the structure.

Comment: Have you tried anything by your own?

Comment: <p>Received date: January 22, 2016 <br>
                Accepted date: February 23, 2016<br>
                Published date: February26, 2016 </p> Can i get the value of published date:

Answer (score 1):

This will work (assuming the arragment of the characters and the digits will stay the same):

```js
var match = $('p').text().match(/Steve\:\s(\d+)/);
$('.value').text(match[1]);
```

```css
.value{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    John: 111 <br>
    Sam: 222<br>
    Steve: 333
</p>
<div class="value"></div>
```

What I do here:

- get the text (without markup) from the paragraph
- match it against a regex

  - find the word `Steve` followed by a colon and capture the digits after that
- set the content of the `div.value` with the content of the capture group

Be aware that this is just a quick example. Changes to your markup and the content can change the result. (e.g. if more than one match is found)

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/iP4uL5/2) you will find an explanation of the regex I used.

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z1ddm2rm/)**

Comment: @LeelaHariPrasad.R You can just use something like `alert(match[1])` to alert the matched value.

Comment: Here is my other html code

       <p>Received date: January 22, 2016 <br>
                Accepted date: February 23, 2016<br>
                Published date: February26, 2016 </p>

How can i get the published date valu in alert box
Requirement is  <div class="date-value"> February26, 2016</div>